# Autowire gives null in customlogouthandler and custom userdetails

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, autowired

My autowire works fine from Controller and all the subclasses down below the controller. But when I try to Autowire any bean (using annotations) from Spring Security module like through UserDetails or through my customlogout handler.

I have read and found two ways to solve it 
1. Remove 
2. Move some code to the parent context.xml. But looks like this doesnt help me.

My web.xml
...

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
        and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/database-context.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring/application-security.xml

        </param-value>
    </context-param>
```

My servlet-context file has the following:....

```
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**"  location="/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.inventory" />

    <beans:bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:messages"></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
```

Please help..

Comment: Why don't you include the relevant parts like the actual configurations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It indicates your autowired annotations are not activated.
Include

```
    <context:annotation-config>
```

in your database-context.xml, application-security.xml files.

Comment: This is an awesome solution.. I added the following in the application-security context and it worked..        <context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.inventory" />                        Unfortunately.. PreAuthorize and Secured are not working still even though I have <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" secured-annotations="enabled" jsr250-annotations="enabled"/>.. Any idea..I know this would require a seperate question though